# How does the simple division works to get a float number instead of modulo?

Tags: python, operators, division

The division in my code doesn't allows me to get a float number as output. My programm is building as a function body which read as input a distance, than counting how long it belongs to get each distance with diffrent routes to drive and in the end giving a number back to me as output. The problem is that in my programm i just want to divide the distance through km/h but I get with the division only modulo instead of getting float. I have tried instead to store it in the variable duration = distance /km_h but that doesn't work either. So here my code.

```
# Die Auswahl wie man die Strecke zurück legen will
a = "Morway"
b = "A-road"
c = "town"
# Das ist die Höchstgeschwindigkeit von jeder Strecke in km/h
m_strecke = 60
a_strecke = 90
town = 50
# This Program will ask for the demand of your way to travel and the distance too
print("give the distance to travel")
distance = int(input("Wie weit wollen sie reisen: "))
print("Wollen sie die Motorway (0), A-road(1), town(2) fahren")
random.choice(["a", "b", "c"])
choice = str(input("Wollen sie (a) Motorway fahren, (b) A-road oder (c) town fahren: "))
# This route we want to drive
print(choice)
# So fast we want to drive
print("Sie können von (30) bis (90) schnell fahren: ")
random.randint(30,90)
km_h = int(input("Wie schnell wollen Sie fahren: "))
print("So schnell kommen sie in Minuten in das Ziel")
print(distance / km_h)
# now we just to want to give the output of the time it belongs
if km_h == a_strecke:
    print("Sie fahren zulässige Höchstgeschwindigkeit(a_strecke)".format(a_strecke))
    print("So Schnell kommen sie in Minuten in das Ziel")
    print(distance / km_h)
elif km_h == m_strecke:
    print("Sie kommen ins Ziel wenn sie a_strecke fahren    würden)".format(a_strecke))   
    print(distance / km_h)
elif km_h == town:
    print("Sie kommen ins Ziel wenn die (a_strecke) fahren würden.".format(a_strecke))
    print("So schnell kommen sie in Minten in das Ziel")
    print(distance/ km_h)
else:
    print("Sie fahren entweder zu langsam oder zu schnell")
    print("So schnell kommen sie in das Ziel")    
    print(distance / km_h)
 # now we divide the motorway with the function mudolo through kilometer per hour and see              
if km_h < a_strecke:      
      print("Das sind sie unter der zulässigen Höchstgeschwindigkeit")
      xspeed = a_strecke % km_h
      print(xspeed)
      print("zur Erinnerung so schnell fahren sie")
      print("So schnell kommen sie in das Ziel")
      print(distance / km_h)
else:
    print("passt alles")
```

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't work"* - time is certainly distance divided by speed, and assuming you're using Python 3.x (based on the `print` syntax) integer division isn't a problem. Are your units consistent (km/h, hours and km)?

Comment: are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: @ jonshrape My unit doesn't consist of hours. I only get as input the distance and how fast you want to drive. I just to want as output the duration of the journey.

Comment: @ Padraic Cunnigham: I use python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when working with Python 2.x you should be aware of the fact that there are actually two flavors when performing division

**classic division**

```
1 / 2       # yields 0 
1 / 2.0     # yields 0.5
```

the latter is always performed, given that there is **at least one operand of type float involved**

**true division**

when working with Python 3x true division is performed. So regardless of whether you divide

```
1 / 2
```

or

```
1 / 2.0
```

it will **always perform true division** notwithstanding whether there are any floats as operands or not.

So the problem in your code may not stem from the division part.

Just open your Python3 interactive shell and type

```
60 / 30
```

to see it on your own - what happens.

For more information on division in Python, you may want to visit this site:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems to be integer division. Just try float() instead of int() in your calls:

```
distance = float(input("Wie weit wollen sie reisen: "))
km_h = float(input("Wie schnell wollen Sie fahren: "))
```

Comment: Based on the `print` and `input` syntax the OP is using Python 3.x, in which case this makes no difference